# Hiding elements in bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have been trying to hide an element using bootstrap `d-none d-sm-block`
but it does not work

I checked if the `bootstrap.min.js` included right and it was

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="d-none d-sm-block">

    <p>Our CFO, Danny, as he is affectionately referred to by his                                 colleagues, comes from a long established family tradition in farming and produce. His experiences growing up on a farm in the Australian outback gave him great appreciation for varieties of food sources. As he puts it in his own words, <em>Everything that runs, wins, and everything that stays,         pays!</em></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved and it was the `bootstrap.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.css` that I forgot to update to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you give it `display: none;` and after that you give it `display: block;` with your classes `d-none d-sm-block`, remove the latter and it works:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-none">

      <p>Our CFO, Danny, as he is affectionately referred to by his colleagues, comes from a long established family tradition in farming and produce. His experiences growing up on a farm in the Australian outback gave him great appreciation for varieties
        of food sources. As he puts it in his own words, <em>Everything that runs, wins, and everything that stays,         pays!</em></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPqbRE

*Note: You could aswell just swap the classes around so display: block is applied BEFORE display: none but its redundant code.*

You can always just use the developer tools and inspect the element to see what's happening and if the classes are applied.

Comment: thanks for answering  but what I want by d-sm-block is just for small screen hide it not for all screens